# How to solve "The byte stream was erroneous according to the character encoding that was declared"?

Tags: utf-8

In [my mozilla log](https://www.iusefaith.com/what-are-the-terms-of-the-covenant-of-settlement-devotional-language-en-article-224-keyword-28), I get the following error:

> The byte stream was erroneous according to the character encoding that was declared. The character encoding declaration may be incorrect.

[image]

Meanwhile, under my doctype meta is UTF8 charset declared:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#"><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"><meta name="msvalidate.01" content="232BB6672CFDF39D90402F9473F59D51"><title>What are the Terms of the Covenant of Settlement ? :. Bishop David Oyedepo, Questions and Answers, + Pdf</title>
```

I am using `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Why am I getting this error, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Sounds like the data is not actually encoded in UTF-8 properly. Just claiming it is UTF-8 in the `<meta>` doesn't guarantee it actually is. That is the responsibility of the software that saved the data in the first place.

Comment: In support of the earlier comment, [see this from W3C](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding#how): _"Note that just declaring a different encoding in your page won't change the bytes; you need to save the text in that encoding too. As a content author, you need to check what encoding your editor or scripts are saving text in, and how to save text in UTF-8. (It's usually the default these days.) You may also need to check that your server is serving documents with the right HTTP declarations."_

Comment: In my case, the *file* encoding (not at document-level) got to be ANSI; converting it to UTF-8 prevented this error.

Comment: @Man Of God: Is you issue resolved? If I open the site you have linked I can't see the bytestream error.

Comment: it just disappeared on it's own after the latest Mozilla update

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in Mozilla, I found one accented character that logged the same message (á).
It was after a remark (`//`).

Comment: Please can you elaborate ? I did not get your answer well

Comment: Thanks. The last place I thought to look was in the comments. There in my notes, which I had copied from jquery docs were several • symbols that caused the problem.