# How to check and solve "The byte stream was erroneous according to the character encoding that was declared" in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, utf-8, character-encoding

this issue was stated in [How to solve byte stream erroneous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71172599/how-to-solve-the-byte-stream-was-erroneous-according-to-the-character-encoding) too. But no real solution was there. Especially no way to check it was named.

This error is shown in Firefox, but not in Chrome. So I am not sure if the issue is only with Firefox.

Unfortunately I do not get more details on that error in the console of Firefox.

Try [this page](https://www.handgefertigtes.de/weihnachten/weihnachtsbaum-tanne-edelrost-deko-christbaum-weihnachten-tannenbaum-metall.html) for example. I only get the issue on product pages. I have verified that the template is UTF-8 with Linux command file and I have saved the template with Notepad++ explicied to UTF-8.

Since this did not worked, I like to check what causes this issue. Does anyone have a clue how to check and determine the chars / content causing this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that that website is loading tons of JavaScript and other resources and inspecting your HTML alone is by far not enough. Exclude single scripts to narrow down when the issue occures. Judging by the ads and trackers being loaded it might even be a resource you can't fix.

Comment: But is there are way to reproduce what Firefox is doing, no see when Firefox has this issue? Maybe a verbose mode. Or maybe a tool for developing that might give you insights in such encoding problems?

Comment: Thx AmigoJack, I found the issue with your suggestion that another file may cause the issue. For everyone else who will have a similar issue. I have itererated over all files of the webproject and used the command "file" to determine the file encoding. Together with "grep -v UTF-8" I found one file not encoded as UTF-8 so I could change that. The issue went away.